# Julia CUDA: UndefVarError: parameters not defined

Tags: julia

I have a program for doing Fourier series and I wanted to switch to CuArrays to make it faster. The code is as follows (extract):

```
#Arrays I want to use
coord = CuArray{ComplexF64,1}(complex.(a[:,1],a[:,2]))
t=CuArray{Float64,1}(-L:(2L/(N-1)):L)

#Array of indexes in the form [0,1,-1,2,-2,...]
n=[((-1)^i)div(i,2) for i in 1:grado]

#Array of functions I need for calculations
base= [x -> exp(π * im * i * x / L) / L for i in n]


base[i](1.)                       #This line is OK
base[i](-1:.1:1)                  #This line is OK
base[i].(t)                       #This line gives error!
base[i].(CuArray{Float64,1}(t))   #This line gives error!
```

And the error is:

```
GPU broadcast resulted in non-concrete element type Any.
This probably means that the function you are broadcasting contains an error or type instability.
```

If I change it like this

```
base= [(x::Float64) -> (exp(π * im * i * x / L) / L)::ComplexF64 for i in n]
```

the same lines still give error, but the error  now is:

```
UndefVarError: parameters not defined
```

Any idea how I could fix this?
Thank you in advance!

Package information:

```
(@v1.6) pkg> st CUDA
      Status `C:\Users\marce\.julia\environments\v1.6\Project.toml`
  [052768ef] CUDA v2.6.2
```

P.S.: This other function has the same problem:

```
function integra(inizio, fine, arr)
    N=size(arr,1)
    h=(fine-inizio)/N
    integrale=sum(arr)
    integrale -= (first(arr)+last(arr))/2
    integrale *= h
end

L=2
integra(-L,L,coord)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first and easier problem is that you should take care to declare global variables to be constant so that the compiler can assume a constant type: `const L = 2`. A mere `L = 2` allows you to do something like `L = SomeOtherType()`, and if that type can be `Any`thing, so must the return type of your functions. On the CPU that's only a performance hit, but it's a no-no for the GPU. If you actually want `L` to vary in value, pass it in as an argument so the compiler can still infer types within a function.

Your `::ComplexF64` assertion did actually force a concrete return type, though the middle of the function is still type unstable (check with `@code_warntype`). The second problem you ran into after that patch was *probably* caused by this [recently patched conflict between ExprTools.jl and LLVM.jl](https://github.com/JuliaGPU/GPUCompiler.jl/issues/214). Seems like you just need to [update the packages or maybe reinstall them](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/error-in-cuda-jl/65197/4).

Comment: Wow, this worked perfectly. I updated to CUDA 3.5 and everything settled. I have no idea how you figured the second problem out, but thank you!